# Почему переменная из одной функции не передается в другую?

Tags: python

```
def printing_of_receipt(upper_border = ' ', line_border = '_', length_of_line_border = 30, border = '|'):

    upper_part_of_receipt = str('{0}{1}{0}'.format(upper_border,line_border*length_of_line_border)) 
    down_part_of_receipt = str('{0}{1}{0}'.format(border,line_border*length_of_line_border))

    return upper_part_of_receipt
    

def avbv(test):
    
    b = upper_part_of_receipt

    print(b) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    printing_of_receipt()  
    test = printing_of_receipt()
    avbv(test)
```

Выдает ошибку:

> NameError: name 'upper_part_of_receipt' is not defined

Comment: Локальные переменные существуют только внутри функции, и их никак нельзя прочитать снаружи функции. Переменные даже с одинаковыми названиями, но в разных функциях будут разными переменными

Comment: andreymal, посоветуйте пожалуйста толковую литературу по python где по полочкам разложены возможности стандартной библиотеки с подробным описанием методов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что `upper_part_of_receipt` - локальная переменная в функции `printing_of_receipt`.

```
def avbv(test):

    b = test
    print(b) 

if __name__ == '__main__':

    test = printing_of_receipt()
    avbv(test)
```

Comment: Точно, спасибо. Можно ещё так сделать: т.е. вызвать ее из предыдущей. def avbv(upper_part_of_receipt):
    b = upper_part_of_receipt
    print(b) 

if __name__ == '__main__':

    test = printing_of_receipt()
    avbv(test)

Comment: @MrStepin Пожалуйста. Успехов! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: Igor, посоветуйте пожалуйста толковую литературу по python где по полочкам разложены возможности стандартной библиотеки. Например: есть метод .format со строками он умеет то и то, со списками это и тд.

Comment: @MrStepin Кхм, кхм... Дело в том, что я Питона не знаю (кроме того, что там в коде интересная система отступов).  На Ваш вопрос я отвечал из самых общих соображений.